# How to make an android app like a recycle bin?

Tags: java, android

I have searched for weeks but I couldn't find any useful information about how to manage files while deleting in android.and want to develop an app to manage deleted files and APKs.can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Last week... on this site.. i saw a post of someone who wanted the same.... Are you deleting those files yourself?

Comment: when I delete any file my app should store that data and it should be possible to restore it back to the storage.

Comment: Unclear if you delete files with any app or only with your app(s).

Comment: How to make an android app like recycle bin? any time we delete a file our recycle bin app should store that. now clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) to read and write data,

The limit of a SQLite database is something like 2TB. Your Android device will not have that much storage space.

You can get the [SQLite tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7T0g5kBYJk), here it is explained quite well.